# Rigid Body Physics - Mesh collision not working

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

New to blender, and have hit a wall getting a test scene to work. Funnily enough, the wall I've hit is that I cannot get my rigid body geometry to hit a wall!

I am creating a galton box simulation to help wrap my head around Blender, and have created what I thought was good geometry for the Galton box - have enabled rigid body physics, turned off "Dynamic" apart from the sphere which drop down, and set the Source to Mesh for the box. The odd part is that most of the spheres ignore the mesh completely - apart from a small section of the mesh, which they correctly interact with! The face they hit in one section, other spheres pass right through just next to it, and I cannot figure it out.

You can see what I mean right here - how can part of a singular face provide collision, but for the rest of it the spheres fall right through? Ive tried subdividing the face, turning it into triangles, everything I can think of, but nothing does the trick. Would anyone have any ideas? I've also uploaded my blend file if it helps:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the direction of your normals? Try Recalculate Normals or Flip Normals and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com (free, permanent, integrated) to share .blend files, then edit your question and paste provided link

Comment: Yeah, have tried inverting surface normals to no effect. 

Thanks for pointing out blend-exchange. Uploaded the blend to there.